# Which NES game is depicted in this "This Kid is Awesome!" meme poster?

Tags: game-identification

What game is this kid in the [THIS KID IS AWESOME](http://images.google.com/images?q=this+kid+is+awesome) meme playing?

[image: This kid is awesome. You will never be as rad as him.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's [Chip 'n Dale Rescue Rangers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_and_Dale%27s_Rescue_Rangers#Video_games).

The screenshot is from the very first level.  [Here's a TAS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9nqMEeuBBk&feature=player_embedded) of the game for reference.

Comment: I loved that game! Very hard, though.